# Overflow hidden breaking layout due to scrollbar width

Tags: jquery, scroll, modal-dialog, overflow

I have a modal that when activated disables background scroll (by setting `html` to `overflow: hidden`).

I have tried various solutions and all of them cause the site to increase in width when activating modal, due to the scrollbar width. Here is my code:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        leanModal: function (options) {
            var defaults = {
                top: 100,
                overlay: 0.5,
                closeButton: null
            };
            var overlay = $("<div id='lean_overlay'></div>");
            $("body").append(overlay);
            options = $.extend(defaults, options);
            return this.each(function () {
                var o = options;
                $(this).click(function (e) {
                    var modal_id = $(this).attr("href");
                    $("#lean_overlay").click(function () {
                        close_modal(modal_id)
                    });
                    $(o.closeButton).click(function () {
                        close_modal(modal_id)
                    });
                    var modal_height = $(modal_id).outerHeight();
                    var modal_width = $(modal_id).outerWidth();
                    $("#lean_overlay").css({
                        "display": "block",
                        opacity: 0
                    });
                    $("#lean_overlay").fadeTo(200, o.overlay);
                    $('html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
                    $(modal_id).css({
                        "display": "block",
                        "position": "fixed",
                        "opacity": 0,
                        "z-index": 11000,
                        "top": o.top + "px"
                    });
                    $(modal_id).fadeTo(200, 1);
                    e.preventDefault()
                })
            });

            function close_modal(modal_id) {
                $("#lean_overlay").fadeOut(200);
                $('html').css('overflow', 'scroll');
                $(modal_id).css({
                    "display": "none"
                })
            }
        }
    })
})(jQuery);
```

Perhaps I can disable background scroll some other way?

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p88Rt/1/

Comment: You will have a hard time getting help without any HTML or CSS... A [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be a great idea too.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check these changes. May be it will help you.
In js fiddle change $('html').css to this one

```
            $('html').css({
               "overflow": "hidden",
                "width":$("body").outerWidth(),
              });
```

And add margins in this way. Depending upon the requirement you can change it.

```
#popup {
    width:80%;
    height: 200px;
    background: lightyellow;
    margin: 10% 8.5%;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    }
```

Comment: Why 8.5%? Not sure I understand.

Comment: No no it totally depends on you. I written this to have this modal popup in middle. Js fiddle screen is small so margins defined in that way. You can define margins totally depending upon your requirement.

Comment: Okay I see. It works great, but when I implement it in my own design it still throws off the margins (only by one or two pixels). It also leaves a gap where the scroll bar was rather than continuing on with the page design. Is there any way I can define the HTML width using JS so that my CSS always calculates including scrollbar width? @Tans

Comment: The jsfiddle provided by you working in such a way like when we click open then the "lean_overlay div" add 17px to the width of html body. So I've changed the body width to existing old body width. If you want to increase dimensions you can increment or decrements pixel in it.

Answer (score 0):

So this works but brings the user back to the top of the page:

http://jsfiddle.net/p88Rt/2/

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        leanModal: function (options) {
            var defaults = {
                top: 100,
                overlay: 0.5,
                closeButton: null
            };
            var overlay = $("<div id='lean_overlay'></div>");
            $("body").append(overlay);
            options = $.extend(defaults, options);
            return this.each(function () {
                var o = options;
                $(this).click(function (e) {
                    var modal_id = $(this).attr("href");
                    $("#lean_overlay").click(function () {
                        close_modal(modal_id)
                    });
                    $(o.closeButton).click(function () {
                        close_modal(modal_id)
                    });
                    var modal_height = $(modal_id).outerHeight();
                    var modal_width = $(modal_id).outerWidth();
                    $("#lean_overlay").css({
                        "display": "block",
                        opacity: 0
                    });
                    $("#lean_overlay").fadeTo(200, o.overlay);
                    $('body').css({
                        "overflow": "hidden",
                        "height": "100%",
                        "position": "fixed"
                    });
                    $(modal_id).css({
                        "display": "block",
                        "position": "fixed",
                        "opacity": 0,
                        "z-index": 11000,
                        "top": o.top + "px"
                    });
                    $(modal_id).fadeTo(200, 1);
                    e.preventDefault()

                })
            });

            function close_modal(modal_id) {
                $("#lean_overlay").fadeOut(200);
                $('body').css('overflow', 'scroll');
                $(modal_id).css({
                    "display": "none"
                })
            }
        }
    })
     $("a[rel*=leanModal]").leanModal();
})(jQuery);
```

Any suggestions?